# Regex newline and whitespace in golang

Tags: regex, go, re2

I was trying to match the below string with a regex and get some values out of it.

```
/system1/sensor37
  Targets
  Properties
    DeviceID=37-Fuse 
    ElementName=Power Supply
    OperationalStatus=Ok
    RateUnits=Celsius
    CurrentReading=49
    SensorType=Temperature
    HealthState=Ok
    oemhp_CautionValue=100
    oemhp_CriticalValue=Not Applicable
```

Used the below regex for that

```
`/system1/sensor\d\d\n.*\n.*\n\s*DeviceID=(?P<sensor>.*)\n.*\n.*\n.*\n\s*CurrentReading=(?P<reading>\d*)\n\s*SensorType=Temperature\n\s*HealthState=(?P<health>.*)\n`
```

Now my question is: Is there a better way to do it?
I explicitly mentioned each new line and white space group in the string. But can I just say `/system.sensor\d\d.*DeviceID=(?P<sensor>.*)\n*.` (It didn't work for me, but I believe there should be a way to it.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default `.` does not match newlines. To change that, use the `s` flag:

```
(?s)/system.sensor\d\d.*DeviceID=(?P<sensor>.*)
```

From: [RE2 regular expression syntax reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/7bab3dc83df6a838cc004cc7a7f51d5fe1a427d5/doc/syntax.txt#L65,L68)

> `(?flags)` set flags within current group; non-capturing
>   `s` -  let `.` match `\n` (default false)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get these properties using regex in a shorter way, you'd like to firstly use `(?s)` [Meaning & use in Kobi's answer]. And for each property use this syntax:
`.*ExampleProperty=(?P<example>[^\n]*).*`:

> `.*` - "Ignores" all text at the **beginning** and at the **end** (Match, but doesn't capture);
>   
> `ExampleProperty=` - Stop "ignoring" the text;
>   
> `(?P<example>...)` - Named capture group;
>   
> `[^\n*]` - Matches the value from the property till it find a new line character.

So, this is the short regex that shall match your text and get all these properties:

```
(?s)\/system.\/sensor\d\d.+DeviceID=(?P<sensor>[^\n]*).*CurrentReading=(?P<reading>[^\n]*).*SensorType=(?P<type>[^\n]*).*HealthState=(?P<health>[^\n]*).*
```

```
<sensor> = 37-Fuse 
<reading> = 49
<type> = Temperature
<health> = Ok
```

**[DEMO]**: https://regex101.com/r/Awgqpk/1